# Problema con WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Tengo un problema bastante extraño con WooCommerce, al menos nunca lo había visto. Tengo productos con impuestos incluidos(así configurado) y si lo veo estando logeado veo los correctos, si lo veo como un usuario invitado, veo otros precios diferentes.

No hay ningún plugin para precios según el rol ni nada por el estilo.

Los precios que veo son por ejemplo 13,95 como administrador y 11,53 como invitado (el IVA es del 21%)

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias

Comment: en tu wp-admin, si vas a Woocommerce/settings/fee and discounts, tenes de-seleccionada la ultima opcion? (enable user role princing)?

Comment: ¿Puedes especificar dónde está esa opción? yo no tengo 'fee and discounts'. ¿Puede ser algún plugin que le hayas añadido?

Answer (score -1):

Encontré la solución.
Hay que poner que la ubicación del cliente es la dirección general del negocio.
Así aplica los impuestos, los gastos de envío y las zonas de envío diferentes.

Gracias de todos modos